# Should Proofreader be a Silver Badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

<sup>The</sup> [image] <sup>badge is as follows:</sup>

<sup>[`Proofreader`](/help/badges/73/proofreader) Approve or reject 100 suggested edits</sup>

However, considering the fact that one needs 2,000 reputation in order to do so:

[image]

I feel like a Silver badge is much more appropriate. After all, once you gain access to this, you're essentially an established member of the community.

Other sites such as Writing.SE have the much lower needed reputation (1,000 for Writing.SE) for reviewing suggested edits, and I think this is one of the reasons for it being carried over as a Bronze badge.

Comment: #You're right. Silver seems appropriate for this badge.

Comment: #No. It should be kept as Bronze.

Comment: I don't get what you try to achieve with this question. Votes here count 0 for rep gain.

Comment: Review suggested edits earns a silver badge at 250 reviews, possibly someone who's achieved silver will be able to tell us how many for gold. I'd guess 800/1000ish. There's incentive for you to keep it up regularly.

Comment: @L.Dutch Oh...I didn't know that.

Comment: @L.Dutch I thought that with enough support that it could be changed to Silver but I wanted to see how the community felt about it. That is the purpose of this question.

Comment: @011358smell it's a thousand. You can find it in the help, both in the [list of badges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges) and on the link for [Steward](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/steward).

Answer (score 2):

Our help center is pretty clear in describing the classes of badges:

[image: badges description from help center]

Bronze badges encourage users to try out new features on the site. They are easy to get if you try!

And that is specifically the purpose of this badge: encourage users to try out reviewing edits.

For those who take the review task more seriously and look for some challenge, there are the review badges, coming in bronze, silver and gold for, respectively, 1, 250 and 1000 reviews.

The reputation needed to access a certain privilege doesn't matter. It's an advantage to have intermediate and "easy" goals.

Answer (score 0):

From the help on [what are badges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges) (emphasis mine):

> **Bronze badges**. Bronze badges are awarded for **basic use of the site**; they encourage people to use all the **typical, routine functions of the site**: posting questions, answering questions, voting up or down, tagging posts, editing, filling out your user profile, and so forth. **Bronze badges are relatively easy to get**.
>
> **Silver badges**. Silver badges are for experienced users who regularly use Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. They encourage **continued participation** and returning to the site by awarding **longer term goals**. Silver badges are more uncommon than bronze badges, but attainable if you're dedicated.

It's a matter of scale. I think it's good as a silver medal. IMO the silver, spiritual successor to proofreader is [Reviewer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/reviewer).

Comment: There isn't really a successor to Proofreader, which asks specifically for Suggested Edits. Reviewer is the successor to [Custodian](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/82/custodian)

Comment: @overlord yes but suggested edits are a queue, so you get a Reviewer for revieweing 250 suggested edits.